# Turn off Accessibility altogether - Is it possible|?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to turn off Accessibility modifiers altogether in the project so that even if the user turns on boild text etc it has no affect in the app?

I seen a link that shows a setting to turn off but i cant find it?

[image]

Comment: _"so that even if the user turns on bold text etc it has no affect in the app?"_ - why on earth would you want to do that? When the user explicitly _requested_ such additional helping features?

Comment: You shouldn’t be using SwiftUI, the whole point of SwiftUI is that all the users preferences are accounted for automatically. That is a UIKit storyboard element screen, is is also for a single UILabel not the whole app.

Comment: Don't do this. Unless you specifically want to discriminate in your app and not allow anyone who has any visual impairment using your app. (Hint: No one wants to do that. Just don't do this.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Just because I asked doesnt mean that I will be implementing this. I had seen the question and was curious if it could be done across the whole app.

Comment: Fair enough. :D Just wanted to make sure. 

Answer (score 1):

If want to prevent bold text, just use the `.font` modifier and supply a `Font` initialised using a `UIFont`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some Text with UIFont")
                .font(Font(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)))
            Text("Some Text with Font")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]